# when ever i try to execute the file it shows me this?

Tags: python-3.x, pyngrok

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "**Storm-Breaker.py**",

line 7, in      from modules import localhost   File:

`"/home/faizan/Desktop/storm-breaker/Storm-Breaker/modules/localhost.py"`,

line 1, in      from **pyngrok** import ngrok **ModuleNotFoundError**: `No module named 'pyngrok'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `pip install pyngrok`, which is used in localhost.py file.
Here is [documentation](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)